# When publishing Adobe AIR application for iOS get: "The signing certficate is not from the expected issuer"

Tags: ios, air, intellij-idea

I have obtained the provisioning file, and certificate from my Apple developer account. When I attempt publish the application I get `The signing certificate is not from the expected issuer`

Possible issue/clue: I created the p12 file on my Macbook but am developing on my Windows Machine.

Comment: How did you create the P12 file? Did you add the certificate from the Apple dev console to Keychain Access, Right Click it, and Export it?

Comment: I performed all of the steps on Windows instead of transferring the produced files back to windows once created on OS X. This worked.